# .zip file MIME Type

Tags: java, mime-types

I'm developing a simple java upload script, where the user can upload a zip file.It works perfectly on Chrome but it doesn't work on Mozilla.

in uploader :

```
   private void processFiles(FileList files) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Files to be uploaded : " + files.getLength());
    if (files.getLength() >= 1) {
        currentFile = files.getItem(0);

        String type = currentFile.getType();
        if (type.startsWith(fileType.getMimeType())) {
            switch (fileType) {
                case ZIP:
                    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(currentFile);
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            new AlertModal.Builder().title(messageBundle.warning())
                    .content(messageBundle.wrongFileType()).build();
        }
    }
}
```

the FileType is enum where i definied :

```
public enum FileType {
ZIP("application/zip");

private String mimeType;

private FileType(String mimeType) {
    this.mimeType = mimeType;
}

public String getMimeType() {
    return mimeType;
}
```

I got the message error of messageBundle.wrongFileType() in Mozilla but in chrome it works, any suggestion?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your log? What about if you open up developer tools?

Comment: You could use the mime type `application/octet-stream`, that should work in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Jaco It wouldn't if a string comparison is made. I suggest just leaving the check off entirely, as the mime type is derived from the suffix of the file anyway, thus containing no actual information about the file contents. I suggest checking for a file header/magic number instead.

Comment: can you explain more please i didn't understand you @Siguza !!!

Comment: @user3816170 Can you please stop the excessive use of punctuation marks?!?!?!?! I basically said "Ignore MIME, just check if file content starts with 'PK'".

Comment: There are quite a few files that start with PK, for example Excel files with an `.xlsx` extensions,  so that approach wouldn't necessarily work. As @Siguza suggest you can just treat any file as binary regardless of mime type.

Comment: @Jaco xlsx files essentially *are* zip files though...